# Django crispy forms work with custom widgets?

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

Following the code in this post, I was able to group the options in a ModelMultipleChoiceField based on another field.  As described in this post, I used a custom widget (literally the one that is in the post):

[Grouping CheckboxSelectMultiple Options in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200911/grouping-checkboxselectmultiple-options-in-django)

so now the form is rendering the way I'd like it to, but I was hoping to improve on the formatting by using crispy forms. however, when I added {% load crispy_forms_tags %} and {{form|crispy}} it rendered the form without the grouping that I worked so hard to achieve...

does anyone know how if its possible to apply crispy forms to a form with a custom widget and preserve what the widget does?

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

No, this won't be possible because crispy forms never calls the `render` method of the widget.

An alternative is to override the template for the widget, in this case `bootstrap/layout/checkboxselectmultiple.html`, to use the grouping as required.

https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap/layout/checkboxselectmultiple.html