# Grouping CheckboxSelectMultiple(two models) Options in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Grouping CheckboxSelectMultiple Options in Django
models.py:

```
class TestSuite(models.Model):
     test_suit = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class TestCase(models.Model):
     test_case= models.CharField(max_length=30)
     test_suit= models.ForeignKey(TestSuite)
```

I tried following fix

[Grouping CheckboxSelectMultiple Options in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200911/grouping-checkboxselectmultiple-options-in-django)

What I'm trying to accomplish in Django's Admin Interface is the rendering of Category using widget CheckboxSelectMultiple but with Category somehow grouped by SuperCategory, like this:

Category:

```
[] TestSuit1: <- Item of TestSuit
[ ] Test_case1 <- Item of TestCase
[ ] Test_case2 <- Item of TestCase
[ ] ...

[] TestSuit2: <- Another item of TestSuit
[ ] Test_case3
[ ] Test_case4
[ ] ...
```

Comment: Any hint about how to implement this?